# Custom comparison and equality in fsharp

Tags: f#, comparison

It seems one has to override Equality in order to override comparison.

Is it true ? Is there any reason I am missing ?

Comment: See [Don Syme's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f-1-9-7.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  It is possible to only have custom comparison

```
[<CustomComparison>]
[<StructuralEquality>]
type Node =
    | Data of string
    | Nil

    with

    interface System.IComparable with 
        member x.CompareTo y = 0
```

Note though that this code will produce a warning recomending that you implement equality on the type as well.  This is generally a good idea.  If you go through the trouble of implementing comparison then equality straight forward (Compare == 0).

Comment: I don't know why, my VS was showing an error. it was probably just the slowness of type inference...

Comment: Thank you. at least I am sure of it now.

Comment: @nicolas VS will use the red underline on the definition of `Node`.  But it's only a warning and not an error.  IMHO they probably used the wrong color for that squiggle