# This type uses an invalid mix of the attributes 'NoEquality', 'ReferenceEquality', 'StructuralEquality', 'NoComparison' and 'StructuralComparison

Tags: f#

The following type

```
[<CustomComparison; CustomEquality>]
type SN () =        

    interface IComparable<SN> with
        member this.CompareTo other = failwith ""            

    interface IComparable with
        member this.CompareTo obj = failwith ""
            
    interface IEquatable<SN> with
        member this.Equals other =
            failwith ""

    override this.Equals obj =
        failwith ""
        
    override this.GetHashCode () =
        failwith ""
```

raises the exception

Error   FS0377  This type uses an invalid mix of the attributes 'NoEquality', 'ReferenceEquality', 'StructuralEquality', 'NoComparison' and 'StructuralComparison'

This is irritating because none of these attributes is applied, but that is already in progress to get fixed - https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/960

I also can find no documentation about this error. The following type however works fine:

```
[<CustomEquality;CustomComparison>]
type DU =
    | L    

    override x.Equals(yobj) = failwith ""
    override x.GetHashCode() = failwith ""

    interface System.IComparable with
    member x.CompareTo yobj = failwith ""
```

So what is the problem with type SN above?

Comment: I don't think any of those attributes apply to classes. What happens if you remove them both?

Comment: There are many examples that have reference types like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536803/custom-comparison-and-equality-in-fsharp . While trying I find that it certainly works with discriminated unions, which are reference types as well.

Comment: I think you are right @FyodorSoikin . Those attributes apply to types where the compiler creates those behaviors, as in DUs or records. For straight types they are not applicable obviously. Still trying to find documentation about that.

Comment: I didn't mean reference types. I meant specifically classes. Not unions, not records, but classes. These attributes make sense for records and unions, because those have structural comparison and equality by default, so you use attributes to modify that default. But classes don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd refer to the [F# Language Spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf), even if it does not include the latest additions which are covered by RFCs. It says on p 172:

```
Combinations of equality and comparion[sic] attributes are restricted. If any of the
following attributes are present, they may be used only in the following combinations:

• No attributes
• [<NoComparison>] on any type
• [<NoEquality; NoComparison>] on any type
• [<CustomEquality; NoComparison>] on a structural type
• [<ReferenceEquality>] on a non-struct structural type
• [<ReferenceEquality; NoComparison>] on a non-struct structural type
• [<StructuralEquality; NoComparison>] on a structural type
• [<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>] on a structural type
• [<StructuralEquality; CustomComparison>] on a structural type
• [<StructuralEquality; StructuralComparison>] on a structural type
```

**Structural type** is defined on p 323:

> A record, union, struct, or exception type definition.

It's not that you cannot adorn your classes with F# equality or comparison attributes, but only `[<NoComparison>]` and `[<NoEquality; NoComparison>]` are allowed.